# Changing state in a function from a button click does not trigger a rerender in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a matrix of cells - small rectangles - in React and a button. On a button click, I want to clear all the cells. First, I create lots of empty cells with some non-empty ones and pass it down a CellGrid component, which renders all the cells just fine. I linked the button onClick to a function, which changes the state (this.state.cells), but it does not trigger a rerender in the child component (CellGrid).

```
class Playfield extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.clearButtonClick = this.clearButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 64*64; ++i){ // all empty cells at first
      arr.push({id:i, status: "empty"}); 
    }
    for (var i=0; i < startCells.length; ++i){ // mark special cells
      var newIndex = startCells[i].x + 64*startCells[i].y;
      arr[newIndex].status = "alive";
    }
    this.setState({ // change state
      cells: arr
    });
  }

  clearButtonClick(){
    console.log("clear")
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i < this.state.cells.length; ++i){ // all empty cells again
      newArr.push({id:i, status: "empty"});
    }

    this.setState({ // change state --- NOT UPDATING THE RENDER
      cells: newArr
    });

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="Playfield">
        <CellGrid grid_cells={this.state.cells}/>
        <Button onClick={this.clearButtonClick}>CLEAR</Button>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the CellGrid looks like this.

```
class CellGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.renderCells = this.renderCells.bind(this);
  }

  renderCells(){
    return (this.props.grid_cells.map(function(cell){
      return (        
        <Cell id={cell.id} status={cell.status}/>);
    }));
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="CellGrid">
        {this.renderCells()}        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone got a hint? Related questions all changed the state the wrong way.

Comment: In constructor, you need to initialise the state as `this.state = { cells: arr, };`

Comment: Your code works for me. I made a tiny update to the first loop in Playfield so they are all set to alive at the start and then I clicked clear and it set them all to empty. Both components re-rendered. The only components I didn't have are `<Cell>` and `<Button>` so I used just `<div>`s for the cells and the base `<button>` tag. Is the onClick being passed through properly in that button component?

Comment: @TheZanke Yes, the console.log("clear") gets written to the console so we reach it. Here's a copy of the project: http://codepen.io/Waschwasch/pen/KNywJq?editors=0010

Comment: @TheZanke Well, the Cell would be the culprit. I am using this.state.status for tracking "empty" inside the cell, etc; but this.props.status would actually clear my stuff. But how can I change the status of it when I click on it now? I need to somehow still use this.state.status in the render, but fetch the new this.props.status data to convert it to my new state.

Comment: @CloseCall Sorry I was writing my answer and didn't see this comment until now, yeah I detail one option in my answer. If `<Playfield>` is the source of truth, that's probably where your onCellClick method should be defined; just have the function take an ID and pass it through to `<Cell>` and then call it with the id of the cell to update.

Comment: Also, Conway's Game of Life \o/ Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually working; you can put a console log in the render method of CellGrid to see that render is triggered when you click clear. The problem actually lies within your `<Cell>` component.

`<Cell>` seems to only use status from props on initial mounting where it copies `status` from props into it's own internal state and then rendering of the cell comes from `this.state.status` instead of `this.props.status`. I imagine you did it this way to use onClick to toggle the cells. What you might want to do is get rid of the local state in `<Cell>` and always render it using `this.props.status` and just also pass an onClick through from `<Playfield>` to `<CellGrid>` and then from `<CellGrid>` to each `<Cell>`.

Also, make sure you're using the `key=` property any time you are rendering components from an array (like in `<CellGrid>`).

Comment: Local state was used to render the children component instead of props. Thank you!